# CoeffFracLength negative or larger than the CoeffWordLength [Fixed-Point Filter Properties in Matlab]

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I have been reading the [fixed-point filter properties](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/fixed-point-numbers.html) in Matlab and I have found that the parameter "CoeffFracLength" can be either zero, negative or positive. And also, it can be larger than the associated word length "CoeffWordLength".

I understand the fractional length as the number of bits designed for the decimal part of a number. I can't visualize how the fractional length can be greater than the word length itself, or a negative value.

I suspect that I am misunderstanding the concept "fractional length". Could you point whether I am wrong with an explanation and providing an example, please?

---

Answer in this link: [mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/fixed-point-numbers.html](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/fixed-point-numbers.html)

Comment: (SOLVED QUESTION)

Comment: and the solution is?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I apologize for not providing the solution. I have found an explanation of how it works in this link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/fixed-point-numbers.html Basically it work just as scientific notation. More details in the link above.